# Is there a way to set a value for each element in an array?

Tags: php

I'm likely thinking of this wrong, but is there a function to set a static value for each key in a PHP array?

For example, is there a fancy alternative to this:

```
$staticVal = 1;
$myArray = array('key1'=> $staticVal, 'key2' => $staticVal, 'key3' => $staticVal, 'key4' => $staticVal);
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Have you tried to use map?

Comment: Will it always be 4 elements?

Comment: @Qirel No, it will not always be 4 elements. This is just an example.

Comment: @jycr752 No I have not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this using `array_fill_keys()`

```
$staticVal = 1;
$keys = array('key1','key2','key3','key4');
$myArray = array_fill_keys($keys, $staticVal);
print '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `array_map()` and `range()` to define your keys, and set them as the keys in your array through `array_combine()`.

`array_combine()` combines two arrays, where one becomes the value, and the other becomes the indexes, in the resulting array. `array_map()` will create the new indexes, by adding the prefix `key` in front of each index, created by `range()`. `range()` creates an array of values, starting from 1, and all the way up to the number of elements in `$myArray`. That creates the number of each index, so you'll get `key1`, `key2` and so on, which becomes the keys in the array through `array_combine()`.

This disregards any previous values of the keys, and is independent on the number of elements in the original array.

```
$staticVal = 1;
$myArray = array($staticVal, $staticVal, $staticVal, $staticVal);

$myArray = array_combine(array_map(function ($k) { 
                             return 'key'.$k; 
                         }, range(1, count($myArray))), 
                         $myArray);
print_r($myArray);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [key1] => 1
    [key2] => 1
    [key3] => 1
    [key4] => 1
)
```

- [**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/MpaON)
- [PHP.net on `array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
- [PHP.net on `array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [PHP.net on `range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 functions which you can use: (not only with a static value)

- array_map
- array_filter
- array_walk

Example about usage of `array_map`

```
<?php
$some_other_value = 'any value';
$tmp_arr = range(1, 5);
array_map(function($value) {
    return $some_other_value;
}, $tmp_arr);

// result
/*
[
    1 => 'any value',
    2 => 'any value',
    3 => 'any value',
    4 => 'any value',
    5 => 'any value'
]
*/
```